# XML File to SQL Additive Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a MSSQL table like such:

```
id     | name
-----------------------------
1        Gerald
2        Ron
3        Becky
```

And an XML document:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Gerald</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Ron</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Becky</Name>
    </Person>
</People>
```

The primary key is ID, the XML document doesn't care about ID's, and Name's are unique.

The XML document changes, and my application should add new rows to the table for any `<Person>` not found in the SQL table.

Sure I can loop through the entire SQL table for each `<Person>` checking for a row and adding the row if it's not found, but is there a better way?

To add additional complexity, If I update a `<Person>`'s name in the XML file, it needs to update the same row that person was at before in the SQL table.

Comment: What language is this to be done in? c# or sql?

Comment: The client application that reads the XML file is in C#, and I'm using MSSQL to store the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @data xml = '<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Gerald</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Ron</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Becky</Name>
    </Person>
</People>'

--Convert xml to rows example:
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as value 
FROM @data.nodes('/People/Person/Name') as T(N)

-- use merge to find rows and insert when not found
Merge Table1 as tgt
using (
        SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as Name 
        FROM @data.nodes('/People/Person/Name') as T(N)
      ) src
on (tgt.name = src.name)
when not matched then
insert (name)
values (src.name);
```

To update row, you need some kind of id in file to identify row to update

Answer (score 1):

You could add an attribute to `<Person>`, which indicated that it was already in the database:

```
<People>
    <Person inserted="1">
        <Name>Gerald</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person inserted="1">
        <Name>Ron</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person inserted="0">
        <Name>Becky</Name>
   </Person>
</People>
```

Comment: So if it's a fresh XML document, load the SQL database with the XML elements, then write a new XML document containing the inserted ID's. 

On an updated XML document, if one of the people changes, add changed="Yes" and import only those, using the inserted ID's, and write a new XML document without the changed attribute.

Would that work?